# Updating an iOS app in one territory only

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Is it possible to push an update to an iOS app, only in a single territory?

I have an existing free app, for which I'm developing a significant update. I would like to pilot this update only in one territory, to uncover bugs and experiment with pricing before rolling it out to all territories.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not possible - you'll have to publish a new app for that. Or you update for all and then do the location detection at start and lock/unlock the new features.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you can cope with your App not being available for sale in other territories.

You can restrict the update to a subset of territories and only those ones will get it but the  App will vanish from the store for all other territories.

Existing customers will not be affected as they will able to use their installed version, but for your trial period you wont get any new customers either (in the switched off regions)