# Who receives updates when I reduce the number of territories in which my app is sold?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

under the 'practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development'- specifically iOS development...

I give you the following:

I'm specifically asking about how Apple/App Store handles the following issue: namely, who receives updates when I reduce the number of territories in which my app is sold.

For example, currently my app is sold in every territory around the world. For my next release, I want to reduce the territories to just one (my own country).

My question is: what happens to the users from the other countries who have already downloaded my app? Will they continue to receive updates (as I will continue to release updates for my own country/territory)? Or will they remain 'paused' on that final version of my app that was available in their own territory, in other words, effectively 'locked-out' of further updates?

I did attempt to research this issue before asking this question and while the two links below certainly 'overlap' my question, I'm still confused about what precisely happens.

If you do know the answer - and let me know - I'd be very grateful!

Best regards, John.

---

Research. Prior questions that were tangentially related to the IOS programming and app development environment. Please take a moment to consider the overall utility of this question before banning for being 'off topic'. I am not talking about planting geraniums here - I'm talking about something that is - or should be - of interest to coders and developers.

[iTunes Connect App Update release for all countries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21623178/itunes-connect-app-update-release-for-all-countries)

[Updating an iOS app in one territory only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842169/updating-an-ios-app-in-one-territory-only/13842270#13842270)

Comment: I would consider this off topic or whatever. But the answers in the links you posted in your research seem pretty clear to me? It seems that it's not possible to update for 1 territory only if your app was released in more. And it seems that the app must be available to the people that receive updates. So you can't lockout territories for certain updates. You will have to arrange it urself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone who has already purchased (even if free) your app will continue to be able to download it forever. If you update the version, they get the new version, not the old one (unless you change the is version require to - then they get the newest one supported by their OS version.

If you pull an app completely (from all markets) you can flag it as being "for legal reasons". this prevents it from being re-downloaded, even from people who already purchased it. But this takes it off all markets, not just some of them.

It sounds like you need to contact Apple directly and describe why you want existing customers to have their right to access your app taken away. Maybe they can make a special case. In general though, they don't allow it.

Comment: Thank you for your response Abhi Beckert! I understand that this question is 'tangential' to the main purpose of Stack Overflow but it is relevant to the broader purpose... developing apps.

Comment: It sounds to me that I might have to 'withdraw' - which is a shame but it isn't a big problem - and then 'relaunch' the app but this time just in my own country. Does anyone know if there is anything in Apple's rulebook that would prevent this approach?

Comment: There's nothing in the rule book, but Apple might be angry if your app is paid or if any of your users have in-app purchases that would need to be re-purchased.

Comment: Happily... or sadly.. there haven't been enough sales to raise too many alarm bells at Cupertino Central! :) In any event, what I want to trial - is making it free... which will probably be the eventual model that goes elsewhere. As a matter of principle though, I think as a developer and the owner of the app, I should have full control to adjust whatever I like, whenever I like vis-a-vis sales/territories etc. (This issue, however, might be a tangent too far for some!) Thank you again, Abhi Beckert! It's appreciated.

Comment: No worries. Personally I disagree with your opinion that developers should be allowed to do whatever they want. There are a lot of crummy/unethical developers out there, users need to be protected from them. Apple cannot judge the character of individual developers, so they just have to apply the same rules to everyone. This is better in the long run, because if developers can't do bad things, then our customers will trust us more — and this leads to increased sales.